# Junit test for session factory failing

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, spring-mvc, junit

I am trying to unit test a DAO Layer method using junit but getting some errors for not finding the xml files. My code files are as follows:

My Test case file:

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration( locations = { "/classpath:web.xml", "/classpath:spring-mvc-crud-demo-servlet.xml"})
    public class ClientYearDAOImplementationTest {

        @InjectMocks
        private ClientYearDAOImplementation  clientYearDAOImplementation;

        @Mock
        private SessionFactory mockSessionFactory;

        @Mock
        private Session mockSession;

        @Mock
        private org.hibernate.Transaction transaction;

        @Mock
        private Query<ClientYear> mockQuery;

        @Rule
        public ExpectedException expectedException = ExpectedException.none();

        @Before
        public void setup() {


            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
            when(mockSessionFactory.openSession()).thenReturn(mockSession);
            when(mockSession.beginTransaction()).thenReturn((org.hibernate.Transaction) transaction);
            when(mockSession.getTransaction()).thenReturn(transaction);
            doNothing().when(transaction).commit();
            clientYearDAOImplementation = new ClientYearDAOImplementation();
            when(mockSessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).thenReturn(mockSession);
            when(mockSessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).thenReturn(mockSession);

            when(mockSession.createQuery("from ClientYear", ClientYear.class)).thenReturn(mockQuery);
 ClientYear.class)).thenReturn(mockQuery);
        } 

        @Rule
        public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

            @Test
            public void checkgetClientYear() {

                ArrayList<ClientYear> clientYearExpectedList = new ArrayList<>();
                List<ClientYear> clientYearReturnList = new ArrayList<>();
                ClientYear clientyear1 = new ClientYear(1, 1);
                ClientYear clientyear2 = new ClientYear(2, 1);

                clientYearExpectedList.add(clientyear1);
                clientYearExpectedList.add(clientyear2);

                when(mockSessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).thenReturn(mockSession);
                when(clientYearDAOImplementation.getClientYear()).thenReturn(clientYearExpectedList);
                clientYearReturnList  =  clientYearDAOImplementation.getClientYear();
                assertTrue(clientYearExpectedList.equals(clientYearReturnList));


        }

    }
```

Here ClientYear is a POJO class and ClientYearDAOImplementationClass is DAO Layer class.

The function which I am trying to test in DAO layer is:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public List<ClientYear> getClientYear() throws HibernateException {

    // get the current hibernate session
    Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    // create a query
    Query<ClientYear> theQuery = currentSession.createQuery("from ClientYear", ClientYear.class);

    // execute query and get result list
    List<ClientYear> clientYearList = theQuery.getResultList();

    // return the results
    return clientYearList;

}
```

Error Stack Trace:

```
SEVERE: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@15975490] to prepare test instance [com.cernerbusinessmodel.test.ClientYearDAOImplementationTest@6b143ee9]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [classpath:spring-mvc-crud-demo-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [classpath:spring-mvc-crud-demo-servlet.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:343)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:258)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:93)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:44)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.buildApplicationContext(TestContext.java:198)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:233)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:126)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:85)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:95)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:139)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:61)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:54)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [classpath:spring-mvc-crud-demo-servlet.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:329)
    ... 25 more

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier.testAborted(Lorg/junit/runner/Description;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:146)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:61)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:54)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

I am not getting where I am going wrong or is there something I am missing?

Comment: The message `class path resource [classpath:spring-mvc-crud-demo-servlet.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist` is very clear

Comment: Yups but I am wondering my files are present in the WEB_INF folder of the project. Is that my path needs to be changed or is not in proper format?

Comment: Is this class in the classpath for test?

Comment: Yes it is in the classpath

Comment: read http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/49585-how-to-get-contextconfiguration-using-web-inf-applicationcontext-XML meybe this helps

Comment: Thank you may be it might help.